# Exporting map from composer in QGIS - text labels have moved in output?

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, text

I am exporting a map from QGIS.  I have some text labels for the title of my map, rendered with html.

All looks good before I export but when I open my exported map (I have tried exporting to both PDF and image), the map title has completely moved to the side and is partly off the page altogether.  The picture below shows the output for the bottom of my map where the title is and you can see it is cut off. It is supposed to say ONEROA. and the other lines are missing letters as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had experienced trouble with finer details of my text outputs from the composer in QGIS.

In most of the cases, I fixed problems like you are having using the actual HTML tags. In the text box properties of your title in the composer window, try inserting the HTML tags you want and try the outputs which most probably will fix the problem.

[image]

```
Try the <pre> your text </pre> for keeping the text in original format 
and <br> your text </br> to control the line breaks
```

You can try using any other common HTML formatting tags to control your texts to finer details. Hopefully, you will get your outputs in your desired formatting.